# Angular UI Router - How to make a parameter required

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
$stateProvider.state('state1', {
    url:'/state1/:param1/and/{param2:.+}',
    templateUrl: 'state1.html',
    controller: 'State1Controller',
});
```

I'm trying to make `param2` required by using regex as seen above. If it's empty, then the default state should load:

```
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    $stateProvider.state('otherwise',{
        url: '/',
        templateUrl:'default.html'
    });
```

Now the results:

`state1/1/and/1` goes to `state1`. Good.

`state1/1/and` goes to `otherwise`. Good.

But,

`state1/1/and/` goes to no state! Neither states are loaded. It's not redirecting back to `/`. What?!

How do I properly make a parameter required?

Comment: What's in State1Controller? Anything in your console?Sounds like something in `state1` might be blowing up. What makes you think that "neither states are loaded"—are you missing a view?

Comment: `state1.html` isn't loaded. `ui-view` is blank. I also put a `console.log('loaded')` in `State1Controller`, and no output to console. No errors either.

Comment: The following plunker is working as you would expect: http://plnkr.co/edit/XTDJ5FAHNh63RoECKwCQ?p=preview

Comment: Aha! I was using 0.3.1. Switching to 1.0.0-alpha.5 works! Is 1.0.0 stable now?

Answer (score 1):

Angular js ui-router url parameters are optional by default. For your case above we could make use of *$stateParams* to check if the required parameter is defined or not. Please check the code below.

```
if ($stateParams.param2=== undefined) {
  // Navigate to home.
  $location.path('/');
}
```

Hope this would solve your issue. Thanks.